# Regular expression to exclude specific bit

Tags: javascript, regex

So far I have this:

```
@(\w+)(?=\s|[.,?!:;-]|$)
```

Which works well for my purpose, except that it includes things like @@jhgdsj which I want to exclude.  How would I exclude anything for more than one @ at the start of any "word"?

[Edit]
Example here: [example](http://regex101.com/r/yH7xS7/1)

Matches desired for bolded words (aaa, ddd, fff):
**@aaa** then @@bbb also ccc@ccc and **@ddd**
**@fff** not @@@ggg

Comment: How are you using the word "word" for this? Is this to be found inside a larger string?

Comment: Your regex itself does *not* match two consecutive `@` characters. Please show how you are using it.

Comment: Thanks for replies! See edit and example given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the start pattern to allow only one `@` at the start,

```
^@(\w+)(?=\s|[.,?!:;-]|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tC7dN0/1)

OR

```
(?:^| )@(\w+)(?=\s|[.,?!:;-]|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yH7xS7/2)

Comment: Thanks, but this would miss other instances in a string, see edit and example

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to not include the space character in the matched result?

Comment: captured groups contains only `aaa`, `ddd`, `fff` See the bottom right corner in the demo link.

Comment: Oh of course, I was only looking at the highlights, thanks again

Comment: +1 for working solution **and** even understanding the question! (I didn't) :)